# Haskell type error when attempting to split function into two functions involving multiparamtypeclasses

Tags: haskell, types

The following imports / languages pragmas are required

```
{-# language FlexibleContexts, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, CPP #-}
import Data.String.Conversions
```

The following two functions typechecks fine (*** kind of**):

```
(++<>) :: (
  ConvertibleStrings a Text,
  ConvertibleStrings b Text
  )
  => a -> b -> Text
a ++<> b = cs a <> cs b

csappend :: (
  ConvertibleStrings a Text,
  ConvertibleStrings b Text,
  ConvertibleStrings Text c)
  => a -> b -> c
csappend a b = cs ( a ++<> b)
```

I tried to define the above two functions as a single function:

```
singleFunction :: (
  ConvertibleStrings a Text,
  ConvertibleStrings b Text,
  ConvertibleStrings Text c,
  Monoid Text) => a -> b -> c
singleFunction a b = cs (cs a <> cs b)
```

---

*

```
xyz :: String
xyz = do
  let s = "test"                      :: String
  csappend (csappend s s :: String) s :: String -- this typechecks
  csappend (csappend s s) s           :: String -- this does not typechecks
```

---

Which gives me an error (below). I don't understand the reason for the errors - the type constraints seem identical, and I'm wondering if perhaps something else is the cause of the error?

```
    • Could not deduce (ConvertibleStrings a0 c)
        arising from a use of ‘cs’
      from the context: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings b Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings Text c)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   singleFunction :: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                                      ConvertibleStrings b Text, ConvertibleStrings Text c) =>
                                     a -> b -> c
        at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:(37,1)-(40,43)
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      Relevant bindings include
        singleFunction :: a -> b -> c
          (bound at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:1)
      These potential instances exist:
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings StrictText StrictText
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings StrictText String
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings String StrictText
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        ...plus one other
        ...plus 21 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: cs (cs a <> cs b)
      In an equation for ‘singleFunction’:
          singleFunction a b = cs (cs a <> cs b)

/home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:26: error:
    • Could not deduce (ConvertibleStrings a a0)
        arising from a use of ‘cs’
      from the context: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings b Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings Text c)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   singleFunction :: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                                      ConvertibleStrings b Text, ConvertibleStrings Text c) =>
                                     a -> b -> c
        at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:(37,1)-(40,43)
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      Relevant bindings include
        a :: a (bound at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:16)
        singleFunction :: a -> b -> c
          (bound at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:1)
      These potential instances exist:
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings StrictText StrictText
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings StrictText String
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings String StrictText
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        ...plus one other
        ...plus 21 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘(<>)’, namely ‘cs a’
      In the first argument of ‘cs’, namely ‘(cs a <> cs b)’
      In the expression: cs (cs a <> cs b)

/home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:26: error:
    • Could not deduce (Monoid a0) arising from a use of ‘<>’
      from the context: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings b Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings Text c)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   singleFunction :: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                                      ConvertibleStrings b Text, ConvertibleStrings Text c) =>
                                     a -> b -> c
        at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:(37,1)-(40,43)
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Monoid a => Monoid (IO a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        instance Monoid Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        instance Monoid Text -- Defined in ‘Data.Text’
        ...plus 8 others
        ...plus 19 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘cs’, namely ‘(cs a <> cs b)’
      In the expression: cs (cs a <> cs b)
      In an equation for ‘singleFunction’:
          singleFunction a b = cs (cs a <> cs b)

/home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:34: error:
    • Could not deduce (ConvertibleStrings b a0)
        arising from a use of ‘cs’
      from the context: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings b Text,
                         ConvertibleStrings Text c)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   singleFunction :: (ConvertibleStrings a Text,
                                      ConvertibleStrings b Text, ConvertibleStrings Text c) =>
                                     a -> b -> c
        at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:(37,1)-(40,43)
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      Relevant bindings include
        b :: b (bound at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:18)
        singleFunction :: a -> b -> c
          (bound at /home/chris/Projects/Haskell/Hart/Hart.hs:41:1)
      These potential instances exist:
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings StrictText StrictText
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings StrictText String
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        instance [safe] ConvertibleStrings String StrictText
          -- Defined in ‘Data.String.Conversions’
        ...plus one other
        ...plus 21 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘(<>)’, namely ‘cs b’
      In the first argument of ‘cs’, namely ‘(cs a <> cs b)’
      In the expression: cs (cs a <> cs b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition doesn't work because compiler cannot deduce intermediate type.
You promise to compiler `a` and `b` are convertible to `Text`, but when you call `cs a` result type defined by calling place, and only after deriving type on calling site compiler checks constraints. Here you immediately call `cs` again on polymorphic result and GHC doesn't know what type you imply.

```
singleFunction :: (
  ConvertibleStrings a Text,
  ConvertibleStrings b Text,
  ConvertibleStrings Text c,
  Monoid Text) => a -> b -> c
singleFunction a b = cs (cs a <> cs b)
```

The case with two functions works because `++<>` explicityly has `Text` in return type.

So if you want to use `Text` as intermediate monoid you should be more explicit

```
singleFunction :: (
      ConvertibleStrings a Text,
      ConvertibleStrings b Text,
      ConvertibleStrings Text c) => a -> b -> c
singleFunction a b = cs ((cs a <> cs b) :: Text)
```